# What are the reasons to use a dust cover protector in a full concert piano while performing?

Tags: piano, recording, performing

In the [Liszt Piano Concerto no. 2 by L'Orchester de Paris with Khatia Buniatishvili](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zuhzdr1lJzY) as the soloist, they covered the top of that beautiful Steinway although they had public and were recording ... I would think perhaps that it was the solution to deal with some light reflection undesired in the recording but I wonder if there are common reasons to do this, as long as the aesthetics of the piano could be (subjectively speaking maybe) affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dust cover is not really a dust cover, but is really a piece of sound absorbing material to control reverbations from the rest of the orchestra.  Lots of clever acoustic engineering goes into these concerts.

Comment: It would be to stop sound reflection rather than reverberation.

Comment: Where were the mikes placed?  if outside the cover, then probably the cover also served to balance the amplitude of the piano against the orchestra.